# SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN not being passed to backend server

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-ssl

I have client certificate configured and working in Apache. I want to pass the PEM-encoded X.509 certificates of the client to the backend server.

I tried with the SSLOptions +ExportCertData. This does nothing at all, while the documentation states it should add SSL_SERVER_CERT, SSL_CLIENT_CERT and SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAINn (with n = 0,1,2,..) as headers. Any ideas why this option is not working?

I then tried setting the headers myself using RequestHeader. This works fine for all variables except SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN. It shows null in the header. Any ideas why the certificate chain is not being filled?

This is my first Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.56.100:443>
    ServerName www.test.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile     /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/www.test.org.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/private/www.test.org.key
    SSLCACertificateFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/ca/ca.crt

    <Proxy *>
        AddDefaultCharset Off
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /carbon>
        ProxyPass          http://www.test.org:9763/carbon
        ProxyPassReverse   http://www.test.org:9763/carbon
    </Location>

    <Location /services/GbTestProxy>
        SSLVerifyClient require
        SSLVerifyDepth  5
        SSLOptions +ExportCertData

        ProxyPass          http://www.test.org:8888/services/GbTestProxy 
        ProxyPassReverse   http://www.test.org:8888/services/GbTestProxy 
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my second Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.56.100:443>
    ServerName www.test.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile     /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/www.test.org.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/private/www.test.org.key
    SSLCACertificateFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/ca/ca.crt

    <Proxy *>
        AddDefaultCharset Off
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /carbon>
        ProxyPass          http://www.test.org:9763/carbon
        ProxyPassReverse   http://www.test.org:9763/carbon
    </Location>

    <Location /services/GbTestProxy>
        SSLVerifyClient require
        SSLVerifyDepth  5
        SSLOptions +ExportCertData

        RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_S_DN "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s"
        RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_I_DN "%{SSL_CLIENT_I_DN}s"
        RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN "%{SSL_SERVER_S_DN_CN}s"
        RequestHeader set SSL_SERVER_S_DN_OU "%{SSL_SERVER_S_DN_OU}s"
        RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s"
        RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_0 "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_0}s"
        RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_1 "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_1}s"
        RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY "%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}s"

        ProxyPass          http://www.test.org:8888/services/GbTestProxy 
        ProxyPassReverse   http://www.test.org:8888/services/GbTestProxy 
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope someone can help.

Regards, nidkil

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I'll answer it in case someone else stumbles upon it like I did.

The issuer certificate is actually at position 0 in the chain from Apache, not 1.  To get the issuer certificate you want:

```
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_0 "%{{SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_0}}s"
```

Answer (score 2):

`SSLOptions +ExportCertData` doesn't add headers to a proxied request, it adds environment variables -- the environment variables that you're trying to add to the headers in your second config (but they aren't in the environment then, since you dropped the `SSLOptions` config).

You'll need both the `RequestHeader set` config as well as `SSLOptions +ExportCertData`.

Comment: Shane, thx for your quick response. When I added the SSLOptions to the second example, the certificate chain is unfortunately still not added. Any other suggestions? I have updated the example in my question to reflect your suggestion. Quick question out of curiosity, why does the client certificate get populated without setting the SSLOptions?

Comment: Ahh, you're missing an underscore - change `%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN1}s` to `%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_1}s`.

Comment: Hi Shane, Sharp eye! The underscore was missing. Corrected it and it still doesn't work :-( This is driving me insane. Anymore ideas? Updated the the example to reflect the correction.

Comment: Huh.  Is there an intermediate cert for it to include as a part of the chain, or is it just the client cert straight back to the configured root?

Comment: Hi shane, No there is no intermediate certificate ... Are you saying that only intermediate certificates are shown with the SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_n? How do you get the root CA then?