# Unable to get Client Certificate Chain from apache

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, authentication, mod-ssl

I'm trying to get the client certificate chain and root from apache to my Java backend.

This is the relevant part of my apache config:

```
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
  RequestHeader set "SSL_CLIENT_CERT" "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}e"
  RequestHeader set "SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_0" "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_0}e"
  RequestHeader set "SSL_CLIENT_ROOT_CERT" "%{SSL_CLIENT_ROOT_CERT}e"
```

I am able to get client certificate but the root and intermediate certs are `null`. I have verified from tcpdump that the root and intermediate certs are being sent to apache.

My apache version is 2.4.6.

I have looked at similar questions like
 [How to get a client certificate chain during a certificate auth with Apache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/906019/how-to-get-a-client-certificate-chain-during-a-certificate-auth-with-apache)
[SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN not being passed to backend server](https://serverfault.com/questions/405901/ssl-client-cert-chain-not-being-passed-to-backend-server)

but the answers did not fix my issue. Any ideas why they are not being passed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for sake of reference.

The reason the `SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_0` and `SSL_CLIENT_ROOT_CERT` were not being passed is because they are extracted from the certificates uploaded by the client. I assumed they would be extracted from the trust store but looking at httpd source code I found that they do not.

httpd calls the openssl function  `SSL_get_peer_cert_chain()` to populate the  `SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_n` and `SSL_CLIENT_ROOT_CERT` fields. From the openssl doc, https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/SSL_get_peer_cert_chain.html ,
the function only returns the *peer chain as sent by the peer*. This was the reason the intermediate and root were passed as null, since in my case, they are obtained from the trust store and not the client.